# Getting Error in self signed certificate in certificate chain in MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate

I have installed Mavensmate but it is giving me this error..

[image]

And I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: try changing name of your workspace.

Comment: @Abbas: Getting Same Error